# Debug Android device is not working on chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have followed [**this article**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) to debug the Ionic app on my Android device.But it is not working.Can you please help me to find where is the problem?

I have enabled the debugging settings on Android device and it is working fine.

Device manager setting for my android LG K8 device.Hope USB drivers are OK.

[image]

[image]

It shows nothing here?

[image]

Comment: have you authorized computer ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you?  @JeromeB

Comment: There is a dialog that pops on phone to allow the connection with computer that has the given fingerprint. Not sure if its on first upload of app to phone or on studio start

Comment: Yes.It shows notification on my device as `USB debugging connected`.Hope that part is fine then no? @JeromeB

Comment: try to connect with adb.
Also, your usb cable could be a power-only cable (2 wires only), try other cables.
Do you have chrome open on the phone ? on foreground

Comment: my xp is that in a classroom filled with same machines, same os and same studio, some students could never connect because of their cable  :-/
try adb devices in a prompt

Comment: Yes, I'm using device's original charge-only USB cable.Chrome open on foreground too.Still no luck? What do you mean by adb? I'm not an android developer.Please tell me how to do that?  @JeromeB

Comment: I have run `adb devices` and it doesn't show any devices.What should I do now? @JeromeB

Comment: Did you write "original charge-only USB cable" ? It means two wires (+ & -) and no data wires. Therefore, you can not transfer data between phone and computer.
Get another cable (weight is a hint)

Comment: Thanks for the info.You have put so many nice info.Hope you can put that as an answer.Actually, my problem was USB driver issue.I have installed correct driver and now it's working fine.You can include that too on your answer.Again thank you so much :) @JeromeB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was the driver and not the cable.You have to install the correct USB driver for the device.

You can find [**it from here**](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html).

Readers with the same issue, look at the comments of the question for hints.